# Why does the closed-shell structure lead to high ionization potential?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, ionization-energy

Why does the closed-shell structure of atoms (those of the noble gases), lead to high ionization potential compared to the neighbouring atoms in the periodic table, on both sides of them, i.e. one electron more than the closed-shell structure or one electron less?